# How use json-api format in playframework java?

Tags: java, json-api, playframework-2.5

You can use the [json json-api format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPOOP.png) in playframework with Java?

I'm using this lib
FasterXML/jackson-databind
with playframework and java

the return of the method to play the standard lib "Json.toJson ()"
does not return I need.

This is my class model

```
public class CompanyWrapper {

public Long id;
public String name;
public String cnpj;
public Long idNode;
```

}

And this is my current return

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "brf",
    "cnpj": "54654654",
    "node": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Test",
      "level": 0,
      "parent": null,
      "token": "h4hdl",
      "active": true
    },
    "active": true
  }]

This is what I need!

[This format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPOOP.png)

Do can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest to detail more your question, what exactly do you want, what you tried.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I corrected

Comment: Ok. :-) And here is your first upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You must return proper header, with `Content-Type: application/json`
I'm not familiar with PlayFramework, but [this should help you.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaJsonRequests)
Everything is probably ok, except your header.